# Lirc - interference from power line

Tags: gpio, lirc

IR remote stops working after switching lights (or other electrical equipment) in the same room. The service of the lirc returns to normal after some time without doing anything.

There are corresponding lines in the syslog:

```
Jul  3 17:44:56 zero kernel: [194967.958217] lirc_rpi: AIEEEE: 0 0 577924e8 577924b8 1c98e 9eb80
Jul  3 18:10:24 zero kernel: [196496.652430] lirc_rpi: AIEEEE: 1 1 57792ae0 577924e8 c30e8 1ca49
```

How to get rid of this kind of interference?

Comment: Do you think this is Pi specific?  If not you would be better asking the question on a dedicated LIRC forum.

Comment: I don't use lirc but the simplest thing might be, if there is a way to check its operability, to just write a script that polls at intervals and restarts it if necessary.  Anything like that running simple checks every 5 or 10 seconds will have essentially zero impact on the system since it will be sleeping 99.999% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem that also turned off the screen for a second or two. We changed the power source for one of better quality and added a capacitor to avoid peaks of current.
Everything works fine now, eventually the screen flashes but it's like 1 in 100 times, acceptable for our use.

Comment: I also have a similar problem with an FM transmitter on a B+ when lights are sometimes turned on or off on the same household circuit.  Super annoying if you have three or four receivers tuned to a frequency that suddenly goes from music to pure static >_<