# House switches light the RPI led strip

Tags: raspbian, led

I'm having an issue with my LPD8806 led strip.
My RPI and led strip are both located inside a lamp, both being powered by a multi output source (not the best one). Before this I was powering the led strip from the RPI and I had the same behaviour, no matter what the source was.

The problem is that whenever a light switch in the house is triggered, one or multiple leds from my led strip are turned on (mostly white. Sometimes a led is pink, or blue). Now, I know for certain that the grid in this house is faulty, but it is a rental, so there is not much I can do.
The RPI is connected to some relays, sometimes this happens when a relay is triggered and a light bulb is opened.

How can I prevent this from happening? Could a capacitor help?
It kind of stinks to be away and when arriving back home to see that the whole ledStrip is turned white. Or to need to switch it off whenever this happens.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

Comment: *"Could a capacitor help?"* -> Possibly.  You do not say how the strip is controlled but this is not an unusual issue (which I have seen at least one person here claim to have solved by incorporating a capacitor).   A very high quality supply may help (e.g., perhaps by itself including sufficient capacitors, I'm not an electrician), but anecdotally I can tell you that supplies commonly sold specifically for the pi do not all fall into this category, so do not bother with any suggestion along those lines.

Comment: It is controlled thru SCLK and MOSI. I'm going to buy a "better" (at least more powerful) power source soon, in order to be able to power another led strip that needs ~7 amps. Should be a power source with 16 amps. I'll see afterwards if that power source (and APA102 led strip) has the same behavior. I'm skeptical, though.Thanks for your input! What capacitor would you recommend for a 5V led strip consuming about 1.2 amps?

Comment: I don't know.  My initial comment (that it is about an effect on the bus controller) is probably wrong; I'm making the observation based on a 3.3V I2C device I have but it is powered through the pi, and there is a reset pin on a GPIO, so perhaps it is more likely one of those which causes a problem sometimes when a light is switched on the same household circuit.  I've never bothered to fix this because it is not much of an issue (and if I did try, I'd use an unrelated method).  [Here's the answer from the other person I was referring to](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50797/5538).